# Error obfuscating Android code

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I have a problem obfuscating Android code. I am using Proguard version 4.7 and Eclipse as my IDE. I changed my `proguard.cfg` to this:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * implements android.view.View.OnTouchListener
-keep class * extends android.view.View { 
  public <init>(android.content.Context); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
  public void set*(...); 
}
-keep class * extends android.preference.Preference { 
  public <init>(android.content.Context); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
  public void set*(...); 
}    
# LVL License binder class
-keep class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService    
# This is necessary for LVL among others. According to proguard doc java accesses enum fields by introspection.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
  public static **[] values();
  public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
#Optimization settings
-dontoptimize
```

When I compile my project I get an error, and I can't solve it. Here's the error:

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lchangebackground/app/OnSwipeListener
Conversion to Dalvik Format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lchangebackground/app/OnSwipeListener
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usually means you are including a library twice, or some other problem with your classpath. Put all your jars under libs/ and clean your projects. Check for different versions of the same library, and including libraries via referenced library projects.

Comment: If you have two files library-v1.jar and library-v2.jar included (directly or indirectly), you will get this error. Examine your project(s) dependencies.

Comment: is android.jar and proguard.jar included?
one more thing, is it okay if i obfuscate using GUI proguard?

Comment: Re: android.jar and proguard.jar -- no, those are never included in your APK. You can use any method you like, just use a config file suited for Android (e.g., one that doesn't mangle activity and service class names). However, depending on your project structure, you might need to tweak parameters to include/exclude jars. Eclipse does this for you.

Comment: can you give me link or step how to obfuscate android code using config file that you mentioned before (android.pro isn't it?).

Comment: By 'config file' I mean proguard.cfg. I don't have a link, but your best bet is to fix/clean up your Eclipse project.

Comment: thanks nikolay. i've solved the error. i using config file that proguard provide and paste it on proguard.cfg. and its works!